# ADB shell get Toast messages

Tags: java, android, shell

I have been working around a Java test framework and ended up with testing an android application which does a lot of toast messages.

The problem is the framework doesn't use anything other than ADB and I can't use any extra libs.

so Is there any way to get the toasted message from an application via adb?
I wouldn't mind writing  hundreds of lines for this alone..

Answer (score 1):

You can check toast messages through events with `adb shell uiautomator events` from the command line. Within your java test framework, however, you can create a method for code reuse that runs this command and parses it for whatever string you want to compare it to with a try block as such:

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator events");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String toastMessage;
        while ((toastMessage = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(toastMessage).append("\n");

        if (toastMessage.contains(myToastStringVar)) {
              Log.i("ToastMessageMatcher", "" // <-- your info message);
            } else {
              Log.e("ToastMessageMatcher", "" // <-- your error message);
            }
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println(log.toString());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This can likewise be directly in your derivatives too.

Comment: I have tried that before and found that it does not show the message displayed in toast, I made my framework use Tesseract OCR to verify captured screenshots and now it works fine around 97% of time. I also found that calling UIautomator crashes apps which are using accessibility settings so my plan to create an app which reads the toast message from there also failed. thanks for the answer, It may help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) you can wait for and retrieve the text in a **Toast** using something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True)

print(vc.uiAutomatorHelper.device.wait_for_new_toast(timeout=10000))
```

however in this case is not using `adb` as the backend (*which is the default for AndroidViewClient/culebra*) but [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public), an alternate backend with more capabilities (precisely this is one of those). You get this backend using `useuiautomatorhelper=True` while creating the `ViewClient` object.

You can take a look at the complete API [here](https://mrin9.github.io/OpenAPI-Viewer/#/load/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fdtmilano%2FCulebraTester2-public%2Fmaster%2Fopenapi.yaml), so if you want to use *java* you would be able.

Comment: Though this would help many people, this will still have the same issue as the adb command.  
The app I was testing used accessibility features (for some reason it relies on uiautomator) and since uiautomator object is singleton it will cause the app to either crash or work incorrectly.  
My problem was solved by just relying on the Tesseract OCR. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: To be precise, the above script does not use `adb` (*you need `adb` only to start the service*). However it's true that UiAutomation relies on the platform accessibility APIs, which is a huge drawback in many cases like yours. Even when your last resource is to rely on image comparison and OCR, AndroidViewClient/culebra could be of great help. [take-screenshot](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/take-screenshot) is much faster than `adb`.

Comment: **AVC/culebra** can also [take screenshots of a single View](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L1126) instead of the entire screen.